# adding numbers in a list with corresponding indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say I have:
`lst = [ [ ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’], [ 1, 3, 2 ], [ 3, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 1, 1 ]]`

How can I add the numbers that correspond with the index?
I don't need a fancy formatted output, just something simple like this
`[ ( ‘a’, 8 ), ( ‘b’, 6 ), ( ‘c’, 4 ) ]`

I put together something like this but it does not really make sense lol I just did not want ya'll to think I haven't tried anything

```
def sums (x):
    add = []
    dictionary = {}
    for i in range (len(lst)):
        ans=0
        for j in range(1,4):
            ans += lst[j][i]
        add.append(ans)
    for i in range (len(lst)):
        dictionary [lst[0][i]]=add[i]
```

I would like to use the length of the lst as the range so that if more letters or numbers are added I would not have to go back and alter the code if that makes sense ! Just need some guidance

Comment: `print({k: sum(v) for k, *v in zip(*lst)})`. Apply `zip(*lst)` to inverse the lists (get `[('a', 1, 3, 4), ('b', 3, 2, 1), ('c', 2, 1, 1)]`). Then the `k, *v` is called tuple unpacking, leading to `k='a'`, and `*v = [1, 3, 4]` for the first example in the list. Then `sum(v)` sums the values, leading to `1 + 3 + 4 = 8`. Finally everything is put in a dictionary comprehension (the `{ }`). Then the final answer will be `{'a': 8, 'b': 6, 'c': 4}`. Which is a dictionary and directly printed using `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [["a", "b", "c"], [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1], [4, 1, 1]]

out = [(v, sum(l)) for (v, l) in zip(lst[0], zip(*lst[1:]))]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[('a', 8), ('b', 6), ('c', 4)]
```

---

Or:

```
lst = [["a", "b", "c"], [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1], [4, 1, 1]]

out = [(v, sum(rest)) for v, *rest in zip(*lst)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[('a', 8), ('b', 6), ('c', 4)]
```

Comment: well that was easy enough. thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` all your lists, and unpack each group of zipped items in two parts: the key, and the rest as values:

```
lst = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], [ 1, 3, 2 ], [ 3, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 1, 1 ]]

out = {}
for key, *values in zip(*lst):
    out[key] = sum(values)
    
print(out)
# {'a': 8, 'b': 6, 'c': 4}
```

Or the same with a dict comprehension:

```
out = {key: sum(values) for key, *values in zip(*lst)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
result = [(group[0], sum(group[1:])) for group in zip(*lst)]
```